With publishSubscribeChannel, in spring integration, if one subscription fails will the other one still run?
Lets assume that the "throwsException" handler throws an exception.  Normally, this will go to the error channel.  However, will the second subscription still run?  Will the message be sent to archiveChannel?
Here is a code sample:
public IntegrationFlow aFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("someChannel")
                .publishSubscribeChannel(pubSub -> pubSub
                        .subscribe(flow -> flow
                                .handle("object","throwsException")
                                .channel("nullChannel"))
                        .subscribe(flow -> flow
                                .channel("archiveChannel")))
                .get();
    }

Thanks

Looks like we do not mention that in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/channel/configuration.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel.
But there is an option like ignoreFailures which lead to this property on the BroadcastingDispatcher:
/**
 * Specify whether failures for one or more of the handlers should be ignored. By default this is false
 * meaning that an Exception will be thrown when a handler fails. To override this and suppress Exceptions, set the
 * value to true.
 * <p>
 * Keep in mind that when using an Executor, even without ignoring the failures, other handlers may be invoked after
 * one throws an Exception. Since the Executor is most likely using a different thread, this flag would only affect
 * whether an error Message is sent to the error channel or not in the case that such an Executor has been
 * configured.
 * @param ignoreFailures true when failures are to be ignored.
 */
public void setIgnoreFailures(boolean ignoreFailures) {

So, as long as you don't use an Executor for that channel definition (and don't have thread shifting in the subscriber), the failure from your throwsException would not let the rest of subscribers to be called.
The logic there is like this:
private boolean invokeHandler(MessageHandler handler, Message<?> message) {
    try {
        handler.handleMessage(message);
        return true;
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        if (!this.ignoreFailures) {
            if (ex instanceof MessagingException exception && exception.getFailedMessage() == null) { // NOSONAR
                throw new MessagingException(message, "Failed to handle Message", ex);
            }
            throw ex;
        }
        else {
            logger.warn("Suppressing Exception since 'ignoreFailures' is set to TRUE.", ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
}


Is there some better way to separate the functionalities? I want both to run.  Can I run them is separate threads or something?  I want them to run independently.

I do want the errorChannel to be called from the failure, because we use that to log the error and send an email out.  However, I don't want the other process to stop.  That can succeed regardless of whether throwsException fails.

So, that sounds more like finally block from Java perspective, but that does not compare with subscribers in this channel which just subsequent calls of, for example, methods in Java inside try block. We don't have such a concept in the Framework (might worth investigating), however you can really implement finally via custom AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice on your .handle("object","throwsException") instead of that "not-fitting" publishSubscribeChannel().

After doing some more research I think my whole implementation wrong.  I am going to try to use witetap with an executor channel.  I think that will work.  I think that will allow it to run independently.

See how WireTap is implemented. It is an interceptor and it does produce message into its channel, before it reaches the handler in the original channel. So, might still not what you want in your logic.

I am not sure the problem I am trying to solve it totally clear, maybe I should have asked another q.

We do have this advice implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/handler-advice/classes.html#expression-advice. But it does not have a finally option. What do you think if add such a capabilities to send message to some channel from its finally block? Right now it is only onSuccess and onFailure. For your use-case it fills like onFinally would do the trick.

I actually had a goal of making multiple threads.  I think executor channel is simpler to deal with for me.  onFinally would always run.  I guess I could do it is with some sort of onFailure call.  However, if it is a separate thread I don't have to write any extra code.  with executor channel, if I make three call and one fails, the one that fails goes to my error channel.  The other two continue.

Actually, if you really could add  functionality.  I would suggest PII protection for logs.  I don't think you guys support that.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78898981/how-to-remove-pii-from-messagehandlingexception-in-spring-integration
