How to remove PII from MessageHandlingException in Spring Integration?
I am trying to remove PII from logs. Is there some way to tell spring integration not to include the payload and header in the exceptions.
public Message<?> hasErrorAndPii(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
      
   if(1==1)
       throw new Exception("Example");
        
   return MessageBuilder.withPayload("Example")
        .build();
        
}

Output Example:
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@5494e631], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=hasPII, headers={hasPII}]

Edit:
Got down voted, but I think this is an important issue.  Maybe some more info will help.
The payload and headers often have business data, which is often pii. So for every exception with GenericMessage, the headers and message get dumped into the log.
Justified or not, I think this is widespread notion, about keeping PII out of logs. However, I don't think spring integration really supports it.
GC_

The payload and headers often have business data, which is often pii.  So for every exception with GenericMessage, the headers and message get dumped into the log.

@Artem Bilan This one where I wish spring would add functionality.  Keeping PII out of logs is a security concern. Justified or not, I think this is widespread notion. However, I don't think spring integration really supports it.

We have an opened issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3222.
I don't think this is just problem of Spring Integration but general concern of logging of the sensitive info.
I even think right now that it is fully not the framework concern to deal with this kind of situation. We just cannot know what is sensitive or not.
You probably need to evaluate what is sensitive in your application and have its toString() implemented respectively. I know that some info is just text. But if it is sensitive, have it wrapped with some PiiAtomicReference which would implement toString() respectively. This way you would know everywhere in the project that you deal with non-public data and it will be logged with mask properly by the framework as well, independently if it is DEBUG or the mentioned exception.

What if you checked a message header? Suppose the message had a header of hideMessageDataInException=true, you could change message. The header hideMessageDataInException can default to false, but if equal to true, headers and message are not displayed in the exception message.

I looked at the ticket you linked to.  I think my issue is just focused to the exceptions.  We log exceptions at error level normally, so at times exception messages are sent to our logs.  I just want the exception message to be changed.  Not all logging.

Doesn't mapper: that all goes to the Message.toString() implementation with respective delegation to all its properties. I think you can write some logging adapter which would filter that info for you. My point is that Message has a lot if info which helps me to determine what is going on and with what. If message processing has failed for conversion reason, when you hind all for that info, you won't be able to determine why. Therefore I don't see why the library has to be responsible for this functionality.

I'm denying some feature in the framework by itself. But even if we implement something, it is not going to be available for you immediately. Therefore I suggest some solution on your side which might be implement much faster, than we trying to figure out what and how can be done in the framework. I don't agree with any extra header though: it increases size of the message and can simply be removed.

I understand why logging that information in the message and header might be useful.  However, I am not talking about changing Message.toString(), I am talking about changing how MessageHandlingException is called.  I would like to remove the failedMessage= section from the error message.

We have not agreed that issue has to be raised: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9416. I see this as a particular case of a broader logging concern. I have already expressed my feeling about the header. But exception without failedMessage would not have too much sense. Why would you log such an exception at all if you are not interesting to understand the reasoning behind?

I am thinking of the errorChannel as an example.
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "logOnlyErrorChannel") )

I created a ticket:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9416

Right. So, do that header logic in your project then. You always can override logging behavior of the consumer of that errorChannel. Still not clear why the framework has to be changed: not all the applications deal with sensitive data. So, mostly pursuing some feature flag in the framework is not enough, since other framework are not aware of this and may fail with similar results. The engineering of mitigating that has to be done in your project.

We can still look at the stack trace, and we have other logging.  I think we will have enough logging to debug issues.  However, we don't have the control to remove PII from that exception message.

I would like something like:
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(MessageHeaders.HIDE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_DATA, "true") )
Then that would turn off the failedMessage= display in the exception.

You can, when you handle message from that errorChannel. You always can override a default one and drop its default logging handler at all.

As I said: that would not be enough  if other libraries throw something similar for the data you feed them. Are you going to ask those libraries for similar flags?

This is not the framework fault that data is sensitive. You have to protect your data independently of the technology.

This no PII in logs thing is a new security concern.  I think it's getting more popular.  I suspect a lot of companies have PII in the messages. It would convenient to avoid dumping it to the logs.

Should we move this discussion to chat?

I guess we could encrypt the data, and unencrypt it each method.  That way if an exception is thrown the data in encrypted in the message.  However, I would prefer not to display it the exception message.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can also have a GenericMessage extension to override its toString() for respective filter. Then use this wrapper whenever you deal with sensitive data.

Well, there is a continuation for this solution. You can register a custom MessageBuilderFactory under the IntegrationUtils.INTEGRATION_MESSAGE_BUILDER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME. That one can always return for you a custom message with overridden toString(). This way any logging for the Message would be covered.

Thanks Artem, great suggestion.  I think that will work.  I'll give that a try.

But I guess your biggest concern that default errorChannel has that logger subscribed. You can declare your own overriding that one: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/6.4/error-handling.html. And just don't have a respective logging subscriber on it!

No, I don't think that would work.  I still want to log an error.  I think over riding the toString() method makes sense.  I am researching how to register a MessageBuilderFactory.

@GC_ Were you able to implement the suggestion from Artem? If so, can you provide me with some sample code? I have been struggling with the same for a few hours now :)

@PetervanLeeuwen You will need: PiiSafeMessageBuilderFactory implements MessageBuilderFactory, PiiSafeMessageBuilder extends AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder, and PiiSafeMessage extends GenericMessage.

Creating the message builder is large task, but it is needed since MessageBuilder hard codes the GenericMessage in a create Message code.  Sadly, the MessageBuilder code is final, so you can't subclass MessageBuilder.

@ArtemBilan Not sure if this is still on your radar, but if MessageBuilder was not final, it would allow more flexibility in implementing MessageBuilderFactory.

Yeah... I know. I might think about something like DefaultMessageBuilder, where that MessageBuilder would extend and you may use for your use-case. But the MessageBuilderwon't change itsfinal`. That's not a goal of that class.

So, I've implemented it like this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9416. Since I don't know what are your use-cases, therefore I left the real PII mitigation implementation out of the framework scope. Hope that BaseMessageBuilder does the trick for you!
